# using scp in terminal

Tags: terminal

I have created a file on a remote computer that I have ssh-ed into. I want to transfer the file back to the laptop I am using at the moment. I see that I am supposed to use the command:

```
scp username@server:/home/username/file_name /home/local-username/file-name
```

But I'm not still not sure of what I should use for my laptop (which is a macbook). For "home' I guess I use the path that appears when I type pwd into my terminal when it opens?

I try this and I get the message:

```
No such file or directory
```

I know this is easy stuff but I've not done it before. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Probably better answered on SuperUser

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would open another terminal on your laptop and do the scp from there, since you already know how to set that connection up.

```
scp username@remotecomputer:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy where/to/put/file/on/laptop
```

The `username@remotecomputer` is the same string you used with ssh initially.

Comment: I have macOS Sierra, and I execute the command but nothing happens, here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/e419ow , any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can download in the current directory with a `.` :

```
cd # by default, goes to $HOME
scp me@host:/path/to/file .
```

or in you `HOME` directly with :

```
scp me@host:/path/to/file ~
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple :::

```
scp remoteusername@remoteIP:/path/of/file /Local/path/to/copy

scp -r remoteusername@remoteIP:/path/of/folder /Local/path/to/copy
```